# Twitter feed programmatically on modern page

Tags: csom, modern-pages, pnp-provision, twitter

Building a mvc app for sharepoint.

Anyone know how to programmatically add a twitter feed on modern page in sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var availableComponents = page.AvailableClientSideComponents();
                //get twitter webpart by guid
                ClientSideComponent clientSideComp = availableComponents.Where(t => t.Id == "f6fdf4f8-4a24-437b-a127-32e66a5dd9b4").FirstOrDefault();
                if (clientSideComp != null)
                {
                    ClientSideWebPart twitterWebPart = new ClientSideWebPart(clientSideComp);
                    //set twitter props
                    dynamic json = JObject.Parse(twitterWebPart.Properties.ToString());
                    json["term"] = @"@microsoft" /*twitter name*/;

                    page.AddControl(twitterWebPart, page.Sections.First().Columns.Last());
                }
```